# Can you mount a shared folder from a samba server in windows?

Tags: linux, windows, samba

I have a samba server on my centos machine and can access the shared folder via windows ... I keep seeing this term mounting in my course and I am pretty confused on what it means does it mean too take that shared folder and mount it onto your system like the downloads folder and how can I do this in windows

Comment: In the case of Windows, mounting a samba share probably refers to [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/map-a-network-drive-in-windows-29ce55d1-34e3-a7e2-4801-131475f9557d).

Comment: Generally speaking, it means to access the share with a manner that is more similar as how you access a local filesystem (instead of manner like a one-time basis file transfer with the help of a client program with its own user interface, command-line or graphical).

Answer (score 0):

Mounting a disk is the process of making that disk addressable by the OS by connecting it to some kind of "name" that the user can interact with. In windows you have options like setting what drive letter you would like the disk to mount to.

Windows users are often confused by the term "Mount" because windows generally mounts all partitions to drive letters on boot, or when a transient device like a usb disk are connected, and there isn't really anything the user needs to do to make that happen.

Windows treats its volumes independently by default, so they are like separate buckets that are entirely self contained.

Linux and *nix systems however have a root filesystem (`/`) and it can only address partitions that are mounted to locations within `/`. for instance I keep my user profiles on their own partition, so I mount that partition to `/home` so if I ever go into the `/home` directory, I am working with that partition. any files I create will be stored on that disk.

Windows can mount volumes to folders inside another disks structure, but it is a non-default behavior, that must be specifically configured.

Linux and windows can mount volumes from lots of different kinds of devices including SMB or NFS shares, though windows almost never uses the word Mount. instead you have options like "Map Network Drive" or "Connecting to a share" (a temporary mount that doesn't use a long lived name).

You cannot mount a SMB share in windows to a folder on an existing volume however. you can only do that with physically attached disks, and you would do it in the Disk Management MMC plugin. You have to make the network share to a drive letter instead.

Hope that helps. it was confusing for me when I was first getting started too.

Comment: To add.. *most* windows programs work just find with the simple UNC path (as in "\\server\share\thingy") where under Linux, "SMB://server/share/thingy" is not typically accepted unless special code is written to handle the protocol.  There is no need to do this hubbub in windows.  Just use the UNC path.  BTW, NOT bashing Linux (we loves it).. but it is just different in how it deals with things.

Comment: Indeed, browsing SMB shares on ubuntu for instance uses a tech called FUSE (User space file systems; uses libsmbclient) to create a temporary mount point in a hidden directory in the users profile. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace Note that Windows does not make a big deal about mounting in userspace, but linux has a more distinct seperation